# Remove editable item from QListWidget if empty

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I'm using Qt 4.8.6.

I have a `QListWidget`. When the user click on an *Add* button, a new item is inserted at the end of the list and edition of the item's text is initiated:

```
void slot_add_item()
{
    auto* item = new QListWidgetItem(QString());
    item->setFlags(item->flags() | Qt::ItemIsEditable);
    listWidget->addItem(item);
    listWidget->setCurrentItem(item);
    listWidget->editItem(item);
}
```

Based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30958374/393756), I'm listening to the `commitData` signal to catch when the user has finished editing the item and to remove it if the item's text is empty:

```
connect(
    listWidget->itemDelegate(), SIGNAL(commitData(QWidget*)),
    SLOT(slot_item_edited(QWidget*)));

...

void slot_item_edited(QWidget* widget)
{
    const QString path = reinterpret_cast<QLineEdit*>(widget)->text();
    if (path.isEmpty())
        delete listWidget->currentItem();
}
```

However that doesn't catch the case where the user *cancels* editing with the Escape key: in that case, `slot_item_edited()` is not called (expectedly) and the (empty) item is not removed.

Any idea on how to remove the item in that case?

Comment: You could probably try to connect to the delegate's [closeEditor](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qabstractitemdelegate.html#closeEditor) signal.

Comment: @Dmitry Works perfectly, thanks! The only change to my code is to bind to `closeEditor` rather than to `commitData`. If you create an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Glad it helped, posted this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect to [closeEditor](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qabstractitemdelegate.html#closeEditor) signal of the delegate instead of `commitData` signal: `closeEditor` signal is emitted when the editor is closed regardless of the fact whether any new data was entered into the model or not.

Comment: There's one subtle case that this doesn't handle, and it's problematic: when the user inserts a new item, the item's text is initially empty and edition of that item is initiated. So good so far. Now if the user types some stuff then press Escape, then `slot_item_edited()` is called but `path` is not empty (it contains whatever the user typed), however the item definitely ends up being created with an empty text. Any idea?

Comment: Hmm, you could have some set of pointers to `QLineEdit` for which `commitData` was called. For this you'd need to connect a dedicated slot to `commitData` which would add the pointer to the editor to this set. Then in the slot connected to `closeEditor` you'd need to check if `commitData` was sent from the editor being closed. Thus you'd be able to tell whether the data from the editor was put into the model.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I did something to what you described but but somewhat simpler: I set an `edit_committed` flag to true in `commitData` and in the slot connected to `closeEditor` I delete the item if `edit_committed` is false.